# How would I collect fees from an liquidity pool on pancake swap?

Tags: solidity, tokens, uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I understand that to start collecting fees you need to add liquidity to a pool e.g. BNB/BUSD Liquidity pool.

So I have a smart contract that uses the uniswapv2 interface to add liquidity to the BNB/BUSD pool.

How would I check how much fees has been generated and what functions / order of functions would I need to collect these fees without removing liquidity.? I don't know if removing liquidity collects fees. Any examples you guys can share / provide? There isn't much learning material for this. Any learning resource, documentation or easy to follow tutorials would be great.

Also do you get fees in the Token A provided (as seen in the code below)?

```
function addLiquidity(address _tokenA, address _tokenB, uint256 _amountA, uint256 _amountB) external
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a LP position, what you get is a token representing a percentage of the total liquidity pool for that pair.  Fees are paid to the pool, so, in a sense you are "collecting fees" but the way to tell how much is to do the math.  In other words take the total pool value * your percentage of the pool = your net position. You can see on the Pancake UI where it says(emphasis mine):

"By adding liquidity you'll earn 0.17% of all trades on this pair proportional to your share of the pool. **Fees are added to the pool, accrue in real time and can be claimed by withdrawing your liquidity**."

Keep in mind that if the value of the assets diverge from one another, you could incur "impermanent loss" which can be very much permanent.  There are other risks as well(flash pirates and rug pulls come to mind) which are likely out of scope for this forum but there are lots of resources on the risks of Defi LP that I would advise taking a look at.

Comment: Have you got example figures?

Comment: I'm sorry, example figures for which part?